# Simulating a mass - spring - damper system

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, matlab

I have a mass - spring - damper system with external force and I am trying to simulate it using Matlab. I want to have a linearly parameterized form and use the least squares method to find the estimators. I have reached the stage where I have the form:

$$ y = \theta^T  z $$
$$\theta = [\theta_1 \ \ \theta_2 \ \ \theta_3]^T$$
$$z = [-s\frac{y}{Λ(s)} \ \ -\frac{y}{Λ(s)} \ \ \frac{u}{Λ(s)}]^T$$

where $\ Λ(s) $ is a stable filter $\ Λ(s) = s^2 + 3s + 2 $ and $\ y $ is the output of the system (the mass relocation) and $\ u $ is the input of the system (the external force).

I am trying to calculate the elements of $\ z $ vector and for $\ z_1 = -s\frac{y}{Λ(s)} $ for example I have done the following:

$$ z_1 = -s\frac{y}{Λ(s)} \Rightarrow \ddot{z_1}+3\dot{z_1}+2z_1 = -\dot{y}  $$

$$x_1 = z_1 \Rightarrow \dot{{x_1}} = x_2 - y$$

$$x_2 = \dot{z_1}+y \Rightarrow \dot{{x_2}} = -3x_2 - 2x_1 + 3y$$

From now on I want to use the `ode45(...)` function but I am not able to figure out how to finally calculate $\ z_1 $ and then put it in the $\ z $ vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the whole backward vector $\ z $ is computed using matlab `ode45(...)` solver:

```
tspan - 0:0.01:10; 

eqtn = @(t,x,y) [x(2)-interp1(tspan(:),y(:),t) ; -3*x(2)-2*x(1)+3*interp1(tspan,y(:),t)];
x = [0;0];
[~,phi_1] = ode45(@(t,x)eqtn(t,x,y),tspan, x);


eqtn = @(t,x,y) [x(2) ; -3*x(2)-2*x(1)-interp1(tspan,y(:),t)];
x = [0;0];
[~,phi_2] = ode45(@(t,x)eqtn(t,x,y),tspan, x);


eqtn = @(t,x,u) [x(2) ; -3*x(2)-2*x(1)+interp1(tspan,u(:),t)];
x = [0;0];
[~,phi_3] = ode45(@(t,x)eqtn(t,x,u),tspan, x);

z = [phi_1(:,1) phi_2(:,1) phi_3(:,1)];
```

It is assumed that the vectors $\ y \  \& \  u $ are known and represent the output and the input of the original system correspondingly.